# problem in create user in Firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i wrote these two functions and called theme in signup button but no user is created in Firebase.(The connection between the app and Firebase is done correctly) so whats the problem?

```
private void attemptRegistration() {

        // Reset errors displayed in the form.
        edtEmail.setError(null);
        edtPassword.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            edtPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = edtPassword;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            edtEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = edtEmail;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            edtEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = edtEmail;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // TODO: Call create FirebaseUser() here
            createFirebaseUser();

        }
    }
```

---

```
private void createFirebaseUser() {

        String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("FlashChat", "createUser onComplete: " + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("FlashChat", "user creation failed");
                            showErrorDialog("Registration attempt failed");
                        } else {
                            saveDisplayName();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages. Check the logcat or add it here to see if there any error messages?

Comment: Have you called this attempedRegistration() method somewhere?

Comment: no there is no error message but in createFirebaseUser function, the if statement is execute and error dialog is showing up on screen. i call that method in button